# Oracle VM VirtualBox is not working

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, 17.04, oracle

it doesn't work no matter what I try... always prints this:

> To re-start the set-up process, run `/sbin/vboxconfig` as root.

when I run `dpkg -l *virtualbox0*` I get:

> dpkg-query: no packages found matching
>   virtualbox-5.1_5.1.24-117012~Ubuntu~zesty_amd64.deb

and `dkms status` prints:

> anbox-modules-ashmem, 8~zesty1: added anbox-modules-binder, 8~zesty1:
>   added

Comment: And when you run `/sbin/vboxconfig` as root?

Comment: it just prints the same error again

Comment: Have you tries re-installing?

Comment: nope, still didn' work

Comment: Though this is not an answer, I highly recommend KVM for ubuntu - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema ii 'unity-scope-virtualbox         0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1 all          VirtualBox scope for Unity
ii  virtualbox-5.1                 5.1.24-117012~Ubuntu~zesty  amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox'

Comment: Is `secure boot` turned off in your BIOS? Did you type `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`?

Comment: @heynnema yes I ran the command... and secure boot is switched off

Comment: And you used `sudo` with that command, yes? Before we `purge` and `reinstall`, lets check to see if you've got some old virtualbox stuff laying around. Do `dpkg -l *virtualbox*` and `dkms status`. Please don't put that output into a comment, rather, edit your question and copy/paste that output. Let me know when it's done. Also, how/where are you installing Virtualbox from... Software Store, a .deb file, download from virtualbox.org, elsewhere?

Comment: @heynnema done.

Comment: @Beulah you had a typo in the dpkg command. Please redo it, and let me know.

Comment: I got the same thing